# Is there a possibility to export and import Eclipse Java Editor Content Assist Favorites?

Tags: java, eclipse

I like to use static imports for some frequently used static utility methods and thus have a long list of Favorites which I don't want to set up manually when working on a new Eclipse installation.

Is there a possibility (maybe a plugin) to export / import those?

Comment: Have been requested as an [Eclipse feature](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=294071). Did you tried exporting Eclipse preferences and inspecting them? perhaps are there.

Comment: Export Eclipse general preferences, open the epf file and search for `content_assist_favorite_static_members`, are your imports there?

Comment: As a workaround you can find them within the file `workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs` at key `content_assist_favorite_static_members`. @LMC no they are not part of the export